# How can I use isValidJSValue to validate a query variable in my client code?

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

I'm writing client-side code for an app that will query a GraphQL server. In a couple of places in my code, I'm passing around data that will eventually get turned into a query variable, so it needs to validate against a specific `GraphQLInputType` in my schema. On looking into some of the utilities that graphql-js provides, it looks like the `isValidJSValue` checker is exactly what I'm looking for, [and its comments even mention](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/blob/master/src/utilities/isValidJSValue.js#L24) that it's intended to be used to do just that.

The issue is that I don't have access to the GraphQL type I want to validate against as a JS object, which is what I'm pretty sure that function is looking for. I'm importing my schema (as an npm depdendency) as JSON, or I also have it in the schema notation. Is there some other utility I can use to get the JS type I need from one of those sources, and then use that to check my data with `isValidJSValue`? Or is there some other way I could go about this that I just haven't thought of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the JSON schema you have imported to construct an actual GraphQL schema instance using `buildClientSchema` here: https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/blob/master/src/utilities/buildClientSchema.js

Then, it should be a simple matter of looking in the `types` field of the resulting schema to find your input type, and then calling `isValidJSValue` on it.

I'm curious, though - why validate the value on the client before sending it, rather than just relying on the validation the server will do?

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I'm building something where I need to count on the shape of an object being consistent in a few different places in order to implement "undo" behavior in my app. One of the places happens to be where I send the mutation to the server, and so rather than building some other type checking in I'd like to just use what GraphQL gives me out of the box. I think I'm going to make it a build-time check, or maybe even part of a unit test rather than anything that gets executed at run time - basically just a sanity check for developers.

Comment: I have the same need but i can not figure out how it works, would you mind to post here a small snippet please? Thanks!