# How to use graphql 'isValidJSValue ' or 'coerceValue' on AWS lambda?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, graphql, graphql-js, aws-appsync

In the workflow of my application AppSync will delivery user inputs (as messages) to an SQS queue, that will trigger a lambda for async processing.

Lambda will validate messages against the GraphQLInputType. For that purpose, I'm using the function `coerceValue` of graphql-js. Got the tip from this question [How can I use isValidJSValue to validate a query variable in my client code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38340892/how-can-i-use-isvalidjsvalue-to-validate-a-query-variable-in-my-client-code), exactly what I needed.

The problem is that the validation code run flawlessly when running local tests within nodejs, but when deployed to AWS the very same code fails with the message:

`["Expected type CreateBookInput to be an object."]`.

Apparently the line `schema.getType(inputType)` is returning only a 'string'  when running on aws.

Already tried with both functions 'coerceValue' and 'isValidJSValue' but no success. Also tried to Promisify my function and use async/await style but didn't make any difference, same error.

```
function validate(object, inputType) {
    let schema = loadSchema()
    let validationResult = coerceValue(object, schema.getType(inputType))
    if (validationResult.errors) {
        throw new Error(`GraphQL: ${validationResult.errors}`)
    }
    return true
}
function loadSchema() {
    let schemaFile = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'schema.graphql'), 'utf8'),
        awsTypesSchema = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'aws.graphql'), 'utf8')
    return buildSchema(schemaFile += awsTypesSchema)
}
```

When running locally I can see that `schema.getType(inputType)` return a `GraphQLInputObjectType` but the behavior differs on AWS Lambda, there in the logs it only return the name of input type, e.g. `"CreateBookInput"`.

Did anyone had a similar problem? Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there was nothing to do with GraphQL libs or lambda at all, the problem was because of a missing JSON.parse on SQS message body, that way I was trying to validate a 'string', not an object.